# How to resume my activity from where user has long press(shut down) power button

Tags: android

I am working on the application,I am having the requirement:if user long press the power button at any time and press again to start device,the activity should start from where the device was shut down.I dont know either this is a valid question or not.
I tried working with:

```
public class PowerMangerTestActivity extends Activity {

private static PowerManager objpowermanager;
private static PowerManager.WakeLock wl;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    callTOWakeLock();
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

}//end of onCreate
public void callTOWakeLock() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    objpowermanager=(PowerManager)getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    wl=objpowermanager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "******MyTag****");
    //You should acquire it when your app starts,
    if(wl.isHeld())
    {
        wl.release();
    }
    wl.acquire(); 

}
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    wl.release();
}
@Override    
protected void onStop() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStop();

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
    callTOWakeLock();
}
/*@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
    if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_POWER) {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, PowerMangerTestActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
        return true;
        TextView tv=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview);
        tv.setText("You press power button");
    }

    return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
}*/
```

}
but not getting expected behaviour.
I have tried to catch `KeyEvent.KEYCODE_POWER`,but not getting how to use for this scenario.
any suggestions?
thanks

Comment: This may be unacceptable to you, but you should **NOT DO THIS**.  It is going against a usability idea called "expected behavior".  You are doing something that a user is not expecting, and there is a good chance they are going to be pissed if you do this.  Just my two cents!  I would try and find another solution to this problem, such as caching useful data in phone storage, and recalling it when the application is resumed/started.

Comment: @Pheonixblade9 Thanks for reply!can i use shared preferences on power button long press button event,still how to save the state of the application in shared pref(either in onPause/onDestroy)  and retrieve in onCreate/onResume of the activity.

Comment: that's a much better way to do this.  onPause still should be called when the power button is long pressed.  The only case (as far as I know) where it won't be called is on a battery pull.

Comment: @Pheonixblade9 +1 forThe only case (as far as I know) where it won't be called is on a battery pull.

Comment: I'll repost this as an answer so you can accept it and close the question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be unacceptable to you, but you should NOT DO THIS.

It is going against a usability idea called "expected behavior".

You are doing something that a user is not expecting, and there is a good chance they are going to be pissed if you do this.

Just my two cents!

I would try and find another solution to this problem, such as caching useful data in phone storage, and recalling it when the application is resumed/started.

onPause still should be called when the power button is long pressed. The only case (as far as I know) where it won't be called is on a battery pull

Answer (score 0):

It is reasonable for an emergency manager app to catch the power button event, so here's one solution, taken from Samsungs support database:

package com.samsung.lockscreenreceiver;

```
public class LockScreenReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
  @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    final String action = intent.getAction();
    if(Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT.equals(action)) {
      // bring app to foreground
    } else if(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF.equals(action) ) {
      Toast.makeText(context, "screen on",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else if (Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON.equals(action)) {
      Toast.makeText(context, "screen off",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
  }
}
```

And the activity:

public class MyActivity extends Activity {

```
private BroadcastReceiver mReceiver;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     mReceiver = new LockScreenReceiver();
     IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
     intentFilter.setPriority(IntentFilter.SYSTEM_HIGH_PRIORITY); 
     intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT);
     intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
     intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
     //intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SHUTDOWN); // won't work unless you're the device vendor

     registerReceiver(mReceiver, intentFilter);
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() 
{
     super.onDestroy();
     unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
}
```

}

You catch power on/off and bring the activity to foreground. The activity then denies all focus changes using:

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    //super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    if(!hasFocus) {
       Intent closeDialog = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS);
        sendBroadcast(closeDialog);
    }
}
```

And you'll have to switch off screen lock, for example using:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.jraf.android.nolock&hl=en

The above app is not protected, so you can decompile it as usual. :)